# How do I get the user ID in any class in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am retrieving a list of communities from search. I want to add a button for **Join** if the current user has not joined the community or **Leave** if the current user has already joined that community. I have created `isMember()` function as

```
public bool IsMember(string UserID, int CommunityID)
{
    var Membership = db.Users.Include(x => x.CommunityUsers)
                             .Where(s => s.Id.Equals(UserID))
                             .Count();

    if (Membership > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

but how can I use this in my search function? I need to pass current UserID in this function but I am unable to do this. Here is my search function.

```
public ActionResult SearchCommunity(string searchString)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        var UseriD = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                             .Select(u => u.Id);

        ViewBag.communityQuery = db.Communities.Include(x => x.CommunityUsers)
                                        .Where(s => s.CommunityName.Contains(searchString))
                                        .ToList();
        ViewBag.Membership = IsMember(UseriD, ViewBag.communityQuery).ToList();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: See how I have removed the excessive whitespace from your code and made it easier to read? Please do that when posting code in the future. Readability is important and makes it more likely for you to receive a good answer.

Comment: Aren't you keeping userid in session after user logged in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will return you an IEnumerable:

```
var UseriD = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                     .Select(u => u.Id);
```

Try to use:

```
var UseriD = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
var userId=User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to obtain the current http context and then you can get the user:

```
var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
ctx.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

If you are in an `MvcController`, you can use the `User` property:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```